# How to use DoctrineMigrationsBundle with yaml file?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, doctrine-migrations

When I'm using Doctrine Annotation file like the example above, the command `php bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff`works perfectly.

```
#src/Entity/User.php

<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping AS ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Repository\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(
 *     schema="data",
 *     name="ts_user",
 *     options={"comment":"Utilisateurs de l'application"},
 *     uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="uk_usr_email", columns={"usr_email"})}
 * )
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="usr_id")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true, name="usr_name")
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=false, name="usr_email")
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true, name="usr_password")
     */
    private $password;
}
```

For some reasons (trait, interfaces), I have to use doctrine yaml file to declare my entity. As soon as I replace annotations by a yaml file, the migration command is throwing this error :

> In OrmSchemaProvider.php line 41:
>
> No mapping information to process

Here is my yaml file:

```
#src/Resources/config/doctrine/User.orm.yml
App\Entity\User:
  type: entity
  schema: data
  table: ts_user
  repositoryClass: Repository\UserRepository
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      column: usr_id
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
  fields:
    name:
      type: text
      nullable: true
      column: usr_name
    email:
      type: text
      nullable: false
      column: usr_email
    password:
      type: text
      nullable: true
      column: usr_password
  uniqueConstraints:
    uk_usr_email:
      columns: [usr_email]
  options:
    comment: Utilisateurs de l'application
```

Because of this error, I supposed that it didn't find my yaml file. Is it in a wrong directory ? Where to put this file ? I saw nothing in source code to declare the directory of my yaml file. I already tried in this directories with no success:

- src/Entity
- src/Resources/config/doctrine/
- src/Resources/config/doctrine/App
- src/Resources/config/doctrine/App/Entity
- src/Resources/config/doctrine/Entity

What am I doing wrong?

*Env: PHP 7.2.3, Symfony 4.1.1 (kernel: src, env: dev, debug: true)*

Comment: Did you change the mapping type to yml in your configuration?

Comment: Thanks @Dimitris ! It was the solution. If you want, you can post the response, I will edit it if necessary and give you the "good answer" tag.

Comment: Go to your command line use bin/console doctrine:generate:entity, first backup your user entity. Allow the generator generate the entity for you then go ahead and edit as needed

Comment: @AlexandreT done. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If automapping is used with Doctrine, you will have to check your orm configuration and set it to load those entities using yml

something like:

```
doctrine:
    # ...
    orm:
        # ...
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            # ...
            AppBundle:
                type: yml
                dir: SomeResources/config/doctrine
```

For more info you can check the custom mapping section of Doctrine configuration in Symfony's tutorials

https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/reference/configuration/doctrine.html

Comment: Thanks a lot @Dimitris